# Problem when fit the prophet model using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis, facebook-prophet

I am using prophet for model prediction.
I have dataset which have datetime, app1Click, App2Click columns.

```
datetime       app1Click   app2Click
2019-03-12       10           30
2019-03-13       57           20
```

There is no NaN values in dataframe , I checked.
But when I create the prophet model and fit the model it throws error,

```
" raise ValueError('Found infinity in column y.')
  Found infinity in column y "
```

what is the issue and why the error thrown.

thank you.
SJK

Answer (score 0):

The input to Prophet is always a dataframe with two columns: ds and y. The ds (datestamp) column should be of a format expected by Pandas, ideally YYYY-MM-DD for a date or YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS for a timestamp. The y column must be numeric, and represents the measurement you wish to forecast.